# Python: How do i sort data in a text file in descending order?

Tags: python

I have a text file data on certain people for exa: Harry = 10 David = 11 Goliath = 13 in each new line

I want to make it such that when i print it displays: Goliath = 13 David = 11 Harry = 10

Comment: add `reverse=True` to your `sorted` call.

Comment: User `reverse=True` argument in `sorted` function.

Comment: Where would i add it? I've tried this sorted_data=sorted(file.readlines(), key=lambda , reverse=True item: int(item.rsplit('=',1)[-1].strip())) but doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

Python's `sorted` takes a `reverse` keyword.  Just set that to `True` and you're all set.

e.g.:

```
>>> print(sorted(range(10), reverse=True))
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Or, in your case:

```
sorted_data=sorted(file.readlines(), reverse=True, key=lambda item: int(item.rsplit('=',1)[-1].strip()))
```

Comment: @tzaman -- Yep.  Sorry about that.  `reversed` is the builtin -- which would also work to get a reversed iterator over the data (but doesn't work for just printing).

Comment: Yes i have heard of this but idk where to add reverse=True